# PNG file Content-Type is Text from Response.ContentType

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I have the following code in a module to direct the input from Response back to the browser. The problem is that I have a couple of PNG file from the 3rd party application that are not being rendered properly. There are other PNG and JPG files render properly. The problem file's Content-Type is being sent back as Text, that causes it to not run the proper output type code. Has anyone seen this before? any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
byte[] responsearr = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string responseStr = encoding.GetString(responsearr);

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;

if (response.ContentType.Contains("image") || response.ContentType.Contains("document"))
{
    if (response.ContentType.Contains("image"))
        Debug.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(responsearr));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(responsearr, 0, responsearr.Length);
}
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(responseStr);
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Until I can verify with the Apache Admins about the MIME types assignments I have updated the code to the following.

```
void RouteRequest(ProxyMappingElement mapping)
{
    //does a whole bunch of stuff between here and there .... 

    // Important problem piece

    byte[] responsearr = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());
    System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    string responseStr = encoding.GetString(responsearr);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(response);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType.Contains("image") ||       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType.Contains("document"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(responsearr, 0, responsearr.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(responseStr);
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}

private string GetContentType(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Substring(
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Length - 3, 3).ToLower().Equals("png")
               ? (HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png")
               : (HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: What if you dont set the content type in that case? The browser should autodetect the type from the content of the payload. Or, you can write some heuristics to detect images, maybe read the first N bytes and look for PNG/GIF/JPG signatures?

Comment: Thanks feroze I did just that. I set the HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png" if it was a png file extension, otherwise I set it to the response.ContentType. I did find another article where someone was having the same issue in PHP from an Apache server and they suggested that the MIME types may not be correctly set on Apache. I sent word the Apache Web Admins to check that on their side.